# LinkedList Elements Swap Problem In C

Tags: c, linked-list, swap

I wrote a program that has many functionalities but I can not swap 2 elements of 2 nodes in the linked list.Actually I can swap 2 nodes by changing their links but I can not swap 2 elements when the user requested 2 elements swapping.Here is my code without any swap operation.Again I have to say I want to do this swap operation by swapping 2 node elements not changing node links.How can I get rid of this problem?Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
     };
typedef struct node nodetype;

void insert(int ,struct node **);
void display(struct node *);
void search(int, struct node *);
void delete(int, struct node **);
int main(void){

    nodetype *p;
    p=NULL;
    int x=0,choice;
    int s_no,k,r_no;


    while(x!=1){
        printf("enter 1 for insert\n");
        printf("enter 2 for display\n");
        printf("enter 3 for search\n");
        printf("enter 4 for delete\n");

        printf("enter 0 for exit\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        if(choice==1){
            printf("enter inserted  no\n");
            fflush(stdout);
             scanf("%d",&k);
            insert(k,&p);
        }

        else if(choice==2)
            display(p);
        else if(choice==3){
            printf("enter searched no\n");
            scanf("%d",&s_no);
            search(s_no, p);
        }
        else if(choice==4){
            printf("enter deleted no\n");
            scanf("%d",&r_no);
            delete(r_no,&p);
                }
        else
            printf("invalid choice\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
void display ( struct node *p)
{
    printf("the content is:\n");
    if(p==NULL)
        printf("the link is empty\n");
    while ( p != NULL )
    {
        printf ( "%d ", p -> data ) ;
        p = p -> next ;
    }
 printf ( "\n" ) ;
}

void search(int no, struct node *p){
   nodetype * loc;
   for(loc=p;loc!=NULL;loc=loc->next)
    {
     if(no==loc->data){
       printf("\nthe number exist in the list\n");
       return;
     }

    }
   printf("\nthe number is not exist in the \n");
 }
void insert(int x,struct node **p)
{
    struct node *r,*temp=*p;
    r = (struct node *)malloc ( sizeof (struct node)) ;
    r ->data = x ;
    r->next=NULL;
    if ( *p == NULL)
    {
        *p = r ;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next!= NULL)
        {
                  temp=temp->next;
        }

     temp->next=r;
    }
}
void delete(int num, struct node **p){
  struct node *temp,*x;
  temp=*p;
  x= NULL;
  while (temp->next !=NULL){
    if(temp->data == num)
     {
      if (x==NULL)
       {
        *p = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
       }
      else
       {
        x->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
       }
     }
    x=temp;
    temp=temp->next;
  }
  printf(" No such entry to delete ");
}
```

Comment: "Here is my code without any swap operation" - What have you attempted for the swap operation? Using that as a starting point would be great!

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag as such if appropriate.

Comment: You need to trim your code down to simpliest possible reproduction of your problem.

Comment: The only way to swap elements in a singly-linked list involves walking the whole list.

Comment: @glowcoder I attempted swap operation with using user entered numbers.For instance,the user entered 12 and 45 in order to swap in the linkedlist.How can I do that?

Comment: Also.. Using singly-linked lists is almost always a mistake, except for data with very restricted access patterns.

Comment: @R.. I believe we went over this yesterday (in another question) where no, the only way is not to walk the entire list. Doing so actually potentially introduces unintended bugs.

Comment: Using singly-linked lists where they're not the right data structure is what introduces bugs. And I've replied to your comments on the other question. The swap hack has the wrong semantics (swapping object identities at the same time it swaps order in the list).

Comment: Also note that the hack is impractical if the objects are giant, and impossible if they are variable-size.

Answer (score 1):

> I attempted swap operation with using
>   user entered numbers.For instance,the
>   user entered 12 and 45 in order to
>   swap in the linkedlist.How can I do
>   that?

I would suggest you extend the existing function with return values, (not tested just the idea)

```
nodetype * search(int no, struct node *p){
   nodetype * loc;
   for(loc=p;loc!=NULL;loc=loc->next)
    {
     if(no==loc->data){
       printf("\nthe number exist in the list\n");
       return loc;
     }

    }
   printf("\nthe number is not exist in the \n");
   return NULL;
 }
```

After that you call search for both values entered by the user.
Then you swap the values in place without changing any pointer references simply be assigning new values. Of course you need to check whether the nodes were actually found (not NULL).

```
nodetype *node1;
nodetype *node2;

node1 = search( userInput1, &p );
node2 = search( userInput2, &p );

int tmp_data = node1->data;
node1->data = node2->data;
node2->data = tmp;
```